# How to customise rails validation error messages with a nested form setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activerecord, internationalization

I have a form with a nested object something like this:

```
<%= form_for(@person) do |f| %>
    <% if @person.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@person.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this record from being saved</h2>

            <ul>
            <% @person.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= render 'person_fields', f: f, :person => @person %>
    <%= f.fields_for :posts do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'post_fields', f: builder %>
    <% end %>

    <br />
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The thing is the validation error messages come up in the format {attribute}{message}, i.e the regular full_messages format. The {attribute} also includes the model name which isn't what I want, I just want to display the attribute and the message.

I'm thinking I can potentially us the rails internationalisation api but could use some guidence; has anyone else managed to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I worked out how to this... just for reference, here's my solution:

```
 <%= form_for(@person) do |f| %>
        <% @person.errors.messages.each do |msg| %>
           <% msg[1].each do |m| %>
         <% if msg[0].to_s.split(".")[-1] == "base" %>
             <li><%= m %></li>
         <% else %>
             <li><%= msg[0].to_s.split(".")[-1].humanize.titlecase %> <%= m %></li>
         <% end %>
           <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <%= render 'person_fields', f: f, :person => @person %>
        <%= f.fields_for :posts do |builder| %>
            <%= render 'post_fields', f: builder %>
        <% end %>

        <br />
        <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [custom-err-msg](https://github.com/jeremydurham/custom-err-msg) plugin in the past and had a lot of success.

Comment: This wasn't quite what I was after, but the source code in the project lead me to a solution, so thanks :) ... I'll post my solution for reference